# Cosine of average of angles

Tags: trigonometry

Is there an expression for the cosine of an average of two angles? I.e., If I know the cosines of $A$ and $B$, can I easily find the cosine of $(A+B)/2$? Ideally, I'm looking for something that can be computed pretty easily by hand, for instance using addition, subtraction, and multiplication (division if really necessary). So far, I've only been able to use the rules for half angles and sum of angles to come up with two ugly expressions involving square roots, which are out of the question.

To clarify, both angles $A$ and $B$ are in the first quadrant, so $0\le A,B \le 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities  Maybe what's more interesting is this expression for the tangent of an average: $\tan((\alpha+\beta)/2)= (\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)/(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)$.  That's form of the tangent half-angle formula.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for the lead, I've actually already spent some time looking at those identities but haven't found a way to apply them. Using the tangent of an average just turns the problem into finding the sine of the average, instead of the cosine. Do you actually know how to use these to solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot hope for an unambiguous solution, because if you know $\cos A=\cos B=0$ that is not enough to fix $A$ and $B$ well enough to get a handle on their average. $\cos\frac{A+B}2$ could be either $-1$, $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Sorry, I forgot to specify that both angles are first quadrant: 0 <= A, B <= 90-degrees. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Why are you expecting a simpler "solution"? And what do you want to use it for?

Comment: @MarkBennet: I'm not necessarily expecting a simpler answer, just hoping for one. I'm trying to work out an iterative approach to refining an estimation of the sine of an angle which can be done relatively quickly by hand. The slope of the secant that connects the lower reference angle (A) to x (the point in question) is somewhere between cos(A) and cos(B), so if I can find the cos of a particular angle between A and B, I can narrow down the interval and repeat, until I have two points close to x, and their cosines.

Comment: I cannot see how can you find something different from what you consider
"ugly expressions":

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \frac{A+B}{2} &=&\cos \frac{A}{2}\cos \frac{B}{2}-\sin \frac{A}{2}\sin 
\frac{B}{2} \\
&=&\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left( 1+\cos A\right) \left( 1+\cos B\right) } \\
&&\mp \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left( 1-\cos A\right) \left( 1-\cos B\right) }.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @AméricoTavares: Well I can't see how either, that's why I asked =). It's not that it's ugly, it's that it's hard to compute by hand. I don't mind doing one or two 3 or 4 digit multiplications by hand, but finding the square root of numbers in [0, 1] is not really practical.

Comment: I think that the numerical computation by hand can only be carried out in a few particular cases.

Comment: @bmearns: Consider the case where $A=0^\circ$ and $B=90^\circ$. $\cos(A)=1$ and $\cos(B)=0$; however, $\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)=\cos(45^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. The cosines of $A$ and $B$ are about as nice as you could ask for, yet the cosine of $\frac{A+B}{2}$ still involves a square root.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks, that's a good explanation for what seems to be the running theme in most of these responses =). I'll concede that there's not likely a better solution that doesn't involve square roots.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: I actually liked you answer better than the accepted one: sign ambiguity is not an issue since all of my angles are first quadrant. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @bmearns Glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are in $[0,\frac\pi2]$ and, for every $\theta$, $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2\theta-1$,
$$
\cos\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(A+B)}2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B}2}.
$$
In terms of $\cos A$ and $\cos B$ only,
$$
\cos\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos A\cos B-\sqrt{(1-\cos^2A)(1-\cos^2B)}}2}.
$$
This is equivalent to a formula indicated by @AméricoTavares in a comment, namely,
$$
\cos\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)=\frac12\sqrt{(1+\cos A)(1+\cos B)}-\frac12\sqrt{(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)}.
$$

Comment: But OP says: "I know the cosines of A and B". So one still has to compute $\sin A$ and $\sin B$.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Do you really see this as a problem in the formula of my post?

Comment: No, I don't. Of course you did know how to express $\sin A$ and $\sin B$ in terms of $\cos A$ and $\cos B$. Your last formula has no sign ambiguity, which is an advantage over mine, now deleted.

Comment: Thanks, @did. I'll concede that I can't escape using square roots for this, so I guess I'll have to practice Newton's method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get 
$$\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2 = \frac{\cos\alpha + \cos\beta}{2\color{grey}{\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}2}}$$
it can be said nice enough, much nicer is not likely.

Comment: And how do you compute $\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$?

Comment: Agreed. This is a nice attempt, but you've changed the problem from finding the cosine of the average to finding the cosine of half the difference. The point is really that I only the cosines (and sines) for A and B, and need to find the cosine of their average without relying on the sines or cosines or any other angles.

Comment: then take the other solution